# Triage review audit failure confusion

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32909873/3367144) is used as an audit on the triage queue:

> #### Xcode adds a lot of  tag in my storyboard and xib file
>
> ---
>
> Just wanna know if anybody has the same issue as mine: Xcode adds a lot of tags into the storyboard I touch. I try to remove but I can't because it keep adding those tags back.
>
> It this a bug of the new Xcode I'm using (7.0.1)?

The audit expects a "Looks OK" and possibly an upvote, which surprised me.  I thought it needed editing.  **I'm not saying the audit is wrong, I just need some guidance.**  My motivation here is not to disagree with the audit, but to improve as a reviewer.

At the time, the problem in the question seemed difficult to replicate based on the information given.  The questions I had were:

- > Xcode adds a lot of tags into the storyboard I touch

  What does it mean to "touch" a storyboard?  What kind of tags were added?  Random noise?  Previously deleted ones?  Tags from other locations?
- > I try to remove but I can't because it keep adding those tags back

  What removal process has been tried?  At what point do the tags reappear?

That's what motivated my "Requires Editing" choice.  Where did I go wrong?  Am I being too strict?  Again, **I trust that the audit is correct,** I just want to know what to do differently.

Comment: That duplicate suggestion isn't a duplicate: *I don't disagree with the audit.* I just want to know what to do differently - specific to this situation if possible. The answer below fits and is totally different than the duplicate suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to know why this audit question does not require editing

Because 10 people upvoted the post, nobody downvoted it, nobody edited it, nobody voted to close it, and nobody flagged it for any reason, so as far as the system is concerned, it appears to be a high quality question with no problems.

So apparently the XCode community (or at least the portion of it that saw this question) feels that the question has sufficient information, and doesn't need a code sample.

I'm not familiar enough with the subject matter to comment on whether or not the question actually contains enough information or was erroneously upvoted.  If it's the latter, and you're confident in this, simply vote/flag accordingly and the post will no longer be an eligible audit.  While rare, sometimes you really do just get 10 people that upvote a problematic post and nobody indicates that it has a problem; there's not a whole lot an automated audit system can do in such a situation.

Comment: In addition, at least three people who *could* have voted to close did something else instead. Triage known-good audit criteria is pretty strict.

Comment: Well from now on I'll use the "Skip" option when I'm reviewing and I see tools and languages that I'm not familiar with.  I probably would've known better if I were more familiar with XCode.  Thanks!